# Testing for KeyError

Tags: python, unit-testing, keyerror

I'm trying to write a unit test that verifies a `KeyError` is created when a bad key is passed to a dictionary.

The code that raises the exception:

```
connections = SettingsManager().get_connections()
try:
    connection = connections[self.conn_name]
except Exception:
    self.log.error("Connection %s does not exist, exiting." % conn_name)
    self.log.error(sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise
```

I've looked and found `KeyError` tests using lambda, but I've not had much luck.  Here is the test I have thus far, but it errors with the actual `KeyError`.

```
def test_bad_connection(self):
    #Testing to see if a non existant connection will fail gracefully.
    records = [1, 2]
    given_result = DataConnector("BadConnection").generate_data(self.table, records)
    expected_result = "BadConnection"

    self.assertRaises(KeyError, given_result[:1])
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`assertRaises()` will *call the function for you*, and assert that that call raises the exception:

```
records = [1, 2]
connector = DataConnector("BadConnection")

self.assertRaises(KeyError, connector.generate_data, self.table, records)
```

Alternatively, use `assertRaises()` as a context manager:

```
with self.assertRaises(KeyError) as raises:
    DataConnector("BadConnection").generate_data(self.table, records)
```

which has the added advantage that the context manager then lets you access the raised exception:

```
self.assertEqual(raises.exception.message, "BadConnection")
```

Comment: Thank you - that explains it perfectly!  For some reason, I was unable to use the 'raises.exception.msg', rather I used 'raises.exception[0]' and that gave me the expected result.

Comment: @OpenDataAlex: sorry; the `exception.args[0]` value is also exposed as `exception.message`; I just misspelled it.

Answer (score 14):

`self.assertRaise()` only takes a callable, so while

`self.assertRaises(KeyError, given_result[:1])`
would give you an actual `KeyError` while testing,

`self.assertRaises(KeyError, lambda: given_result[:1])`
should work.

In general:
Does not work:  `self.assertRaises(KeyError, mydict[mykey])`   #KeyError in tests
Does work:  `self.assertRaises(KeyError, lambda:  mydict[mykey])`
Does work:  `self.assertRaises(KeyError, mydict.__getitem__, mykey)`  #but is requires an actual dict, instead of a function

Comment: This answer was easier to understand and reason with than the accepted answer, because it provides a more general solution and not a custom solution. Thanks!

Comment: `self.assertRaises(KeyError, mydict.get(mykey))` also works.